# 12 month moving average by person, date

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, moving-average

I have a table [production] that contains the following structure:

```
rep (char(10))    
,cyc_date (datetime) ---- already standardized to mm/01/yyyy
,amt (decimal)
```

I have data for each rep from 1/1/2011 to 8/1/2013.  What I want to be able to do is create a 12 month moving average beginning 1/1/2012 for each rep, as follows:

```
rep    cyc_dt    12moAvg
-------------------------
A      1/1/2012    10000.01
A      2/1/2012    13510.05
.      ........    ........
A      8/1/2013    22101.32
B      1/1/2012    98328.22
B      ........    ........
```

where each row represents the 12 month moving average for said rep at stated time.  I found some examples that were vaguely close and I tried them to no avail.  It seems the addition of a group by rep component is the major departure from other examples.

This is about as far as I got:

```
SELECT
    rep,
    cyc_date,
    (
        SELECT Avg([amt])
        FROM production Q
        WHERE Q.[cyc_date] BETWEEN DateAdd("yyyy",-1,[cyc_date]+1) AND [cyc_date]
    ) AS 12moavg
FROM production
```

That query seems to pull an overall average or sum, since there is no grouping in the correlated subquery. When I try to group by, I get an error that it can only return at most one row.

Comment: Are the values in `cyc_dt` always the first day of the month?

Comment: Yes, sorry that wasn't clear.  Dates are standardized to 1st of the month for each cyc_dt.

Comment: Thank you.  Then for `rep` A and `cyc_dt` 1/1/2012, does `12moAvg` represent  average of `amt` values from 1/1/2011 to 12/1/2011, or would you also include `amt` value from 1/1/2012 in that average?

Comment: I guess to make it a true 12 month period, current period inclusive, I would say the value at 1/1/2012 should include data from 2/1/2011 to 1/1/2012, endpoints inclusive.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.  Now which of these are you familiar with: `DateAdd()`; correlated subqueries; `DAvg()`?

Comment: DateAdd and correlated subqueries.  I was working with these two in my original attempt (borrowed from a previous example).  However, I'm not averse to dimensional functions like DAVg.  Whatever is in your wheelhouse, good sir!

Comment: Show us the SQL from your `DateAdd()` attempt, describe how its result set differs from what you need, and include the full text of any error message.  If you do that, someone can show you how to fix it.

Comment: This site [link](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1662907) contains the code example. See post 6 Oct 11 16:14. This is about as far as I got: `SELECT rep, cyc_date, (SELECT Avg([amt]) FROM production Q WHERE Q.[cyc_date] BETWEEN DateAdd("yyyy",-1,[cyc_date]+1) AND [cyc_date]) AS 12moavg FROM production`. This seems to pull an overall average or sum, since there is no grouping in the correlated subquery. When I try to group by, I get an error that it can only return at most one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may work with 2 adjustments to the correlated subquery.

1. Subtract 11 months in the `DateAdd()` expression.
2. Include another `WHERE` condition to limit the average to the same `rep` as the current row of the parent (containing) query.

```sql
SELECT
    p.rep,
    p.cyc_date,
    (
        SELECT Avg(Q.amt)
        FROM production AS Q
        WHERE
                Q.rep = p.rep
            AND
                Q.cyc_date BETWEEN DateAdd("m", -11, p.cyc_date)
                    AND p.cyc_date
    ) AS [12moavg]
FROM production AS p;
```

Correlated subqueries can be slow.  Make sure to index `rep` and `cyc_date` to limit the pain with this one.

Comment: Bingo.  That worked perfectly.  I didn't think about setting the rep correlation explicitly in the WHERE statement.  My mind was totally going in an aggregation route.  Thanks so much for your help.  Hopefully this will help others, too.

Comment: Also, agree with indexing on non-aggregate fields.  Fortunately the data is not excessively large, so it runs relatively quickly.

Comment: OK, good.  Once you showed us the SQL, I could see you were close with that correlated subquery but just needed to constrain the average by `rep`.  Thanks for showing the SQL!