# R - Calculating 12 month moving average on panel data

Tags: r, plyr, moving-average, panel-data

First, full disclosure.  I attempted to do this strictly in MS Access with correlated subqueries, and had some help on this post [12 month moving average by person, date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299039/12-month-moving-average-by-person-date). I originally thought my data would be small enough to chug through, but it is awful.  As an alternative, I'm going to try running this in R and then writing results to a new table in MS Access.  I have data such that I have the following fields:

```
rep, cyc_date, amt
```

Following the linked example by Andrie for a rolling 5-year period (as opposed to the 5-year average) [R: Calculating 5 year averages in panel data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954088/r-calculating-5-year-averages-in-panel-data), I am trying to get rolling 12 month average for `amt` field by `rep`.  Here is my code:

```
library(zoo)
library(plyr)
library(RODBC)

# Pull data from local MS Access database.  The referenced sqlFetch is a query
# that pulls the data, ordered by `rep`, then `cyc_date`

channel <- odbcConnectAccess2007("C://MyDB.accdb")
data <- data.frame(sqlFetch(channel, "MyView"))

# Ensure coercion of `cyc_date` to date type
data$cyc_date <- as.Date(data$cyc_date)

# Function (take from post above)
rollmean12 <- function(x) {
                 rollmean(x, 12)
              }
# Calculate rolling average by person
rollvec <- ddply(data, .(data$rep), rollmean12(data$amt))
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in llply(.data = .data, .fun = .fun, ..., .progress = .progress,  : 
.fun is not a function.
```

I'm not sure why this is happening.  Do I need to explicitly convert `data` to a `zoo` object?  If so, not sure how to handle the extra dimensionality resulting from the `person_id` field.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the exact `ddply` code from the answer you are working from in the link?  Did not that work?  It works for me (but I don't have your dataset).  An alternative way to use `ddply` for a single column would be `ddply(dat1, .(rep), summarize, rollamt = rollmean12(amt) )`.

Comment: Close.  Unfortunately, I need to add the data back into my original data set, so the `summarize` call drops the cycle date.  I realize that requirement wasn't specified in my original post.  I found a nice approach that eliminates the `ddply` call.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this code on the following post: [applying rolling mean by group in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644494/applying-rolling-mean-by-group-in-r?rq=1)

```
data$movavg <- ave(data$amt, data$rep, FUN = function(x) rollmean(x, k=12, align="right", na.pad=T)).
```

`ave` saves the day!

Answer (score 0):

Just some hints, as I don't work at all with time series: `ddply` requires a data frame input, so don't convert it to a `zoo` object.  `.(data$rep)` I think should be just `.(rep)`, and `rollmean12` should not be called with arguments.  Rather, you should re-write the function to extract the columns you want.  So, approximately something like this:

```
rollmean12 <- function(x) rollmean(x$amt, 12)
```

If you do `?ddply` there is a link to a very helpful publication in JSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `tidyquant` library

```
x %>% tq_mutate(
    # tq_mutate args
    select     = amt,
    mutate_fun = rollapply, 
    col_rename = "rollmean12", #### 
    # rollapply args
    width      = 12,
    align      = "right",
    FUN        = mean,
    # mean args
    na.rm      = TRUE
  )
```